# Add method to ModelViewset Endpoint without having to call the method name in the URL

Tags: python, css, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have two separate endpoints that "accepts" and "declines" each applicant on the system respectively.

Endpoint #1:

```
...api/v1/applicants/{ID}/accept
```

Endpoint #2:

```
...api/v1/applicants/{ID}/decline
```

Now, I'm refactoring and trying to combine the Endpoints into one, such that the following URL can be used to **accept** and **decline** an applicant, while maintaining :

```
...api/v1/applicants/{ID}/
```

The purpose of doing this is to conform the endpoints to REST methodologies.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried creating a hidden method [starting with underscore - eg: _someFunction() using a PUT request method]. This didn't work.

I know I could also do it through the **serializers.py** file but don't know how as I haven't seen an example online.

Here is the **accept** class. The **decline** is similar with minor changes:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
def accept(self, request, pk):
    data = request.data

    if request.user.user_type == "2":

        if Applicant.objects.filter(id=pk).exists():
            applicant = Applicant.objects.get(id=pk)
            if applicant.status == '1':
                applicant.status = '2'
                applicant.save()

                # Hash the ID of the particular applicant so it can be used for verification
                # make this a function during refactoring

                hashids = Hashids(salt=HASH_SALT, min_length=16)
                hashid = hashids.encode(applicant.id)

                # send email with the link to the applicant
                # make this a function too

                SENDER="xxx@example.com"
                SUBJECT="Congratulations, you've been accepted!"
                MESSAGE = """

                    Hello {}, \n                    
                    Your application as a Journalist on example.com was accepted.\n 
                    Copy your OTP: {} and Click here "https://example.com/verify-otp/ to enter it.\n
                    Cheers!
                    """.format(applicant.first_name, hashid)

                send_mail(SUBJECT, MESSAGE, SENDER, [applicant.email], fail_silently=False)

                # generate a response object
                queryset = applicant
                serializer = ApplicantSerializer(queryset)
                return Response(jsend.success({'applicants':serializer.data}))

            else:
                return Response((jsend.error("Cannot perform such action for this applicant")), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        else:
            return Response((jsend.error('Cannot find an applicant with ID of {}'.format(pk))), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        return Response((jsend.error("You are not authorized to perform this action")), status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the perform_update() or update() of the ModelViewSet for example using perform_update:

```
 def perform_update(self, serializer):
    applicant = self.get_object()
    if applicant.status == '1':
            serializer.save(status='2')
    #rest of your logic
    serializer.save()
```

Hope it helps. Note you can get the request inside perform_update like this:

```
self.request
```